# Run shell script from website

Tags: php, linux

I need to run shell a script from a php-powered website. I set execution rights on my script.

```
chmod +x AppRaspberry.exe
```

This is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/pi/program/Debug/AppRaspberry.exe start
```

My website and c# application is on raspberry pi 3.  The idea of everything is when user is ready with configuration on his settings to run c# application and it reads user settings  from MySQL database.
I use this code to run script but it doesn't work, so tried with shell exec but my php don't recognize this method.

```
if (!empty($_POST['start']))
{
exec("/home/pi/script/start.sh");
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I don't get error. When i press button on my website to start a program my script doesn't start the application.Now i use: shell_exec('/home/pi/script/start.sh')

Comment: Is the php (Apache?) running with the same user as the script? It might not have read permissions to the script. See the server's log (if Apache, it should be in `/var/log/apache`

Comment: Also see the php.ini you are using. Some configurations prevent php from running certain functions for security reasons. Check if the function exists.

Comment: I search in php.ini but i don't find anything,then i look in log but also nothing. I'm really very confused about how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's shell_exec not schell_exec

Comment: Thanks, i fixed my mistake  but it doesn't work again.I never use this shell_exec()

Comment: Command is corrent but I think syntax which you are using to exec is not correct. Either shell script path is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Backtick operator works the same as shell_exec function, but saving some typing:
`chmod 666 file.txt`

(note that that's backtick character and not single quotes)